# Selecting single row as dataframe with DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series in a dataframe with DatetimeIndex like that:

```
import pandas as pd
dates= ["2015-10-01 00:00:00",
         "2015-10-01 01:00:00",
         "2015-10-01 02:00:00",
         "2015-10-01 03:00:00",
         "2015-10-01 04:00:00"]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.DatetimeIndex(dates))
df["values"] = range(0,5)

Out[]:
                     values
2015-10-01 00:00:00       0
2015-10-01 01:00:00       1
2015-10-01 02:00:00       2
2015-10-01 03:00:00       3
2015-10-01 04:00:00       4
```

I would like to as simple clean as possible select a row looking like that, based on the date being the key, e.g. "2015-10-01 02:00:00":

```
Out[]:
                     values
2015-10-01 02:00:00       2
```

Simply using indexing results in a key error:

```
df["2015-10-01 02:00:00"]
Out[]:
KeyError: '2015-10-01 02:00:00'
```

Similarly this:

```
df.loc[["2015-10-01 02:00:00"]]
Out[]:
KeyError: "None of [['2015-10-01 02:00:00']] are in the [index]"
```

These surprisingly (?) result in the same series as follows:

```
df.loc["2015-10-01 02:00:00"]
Out[]:
values    2
Name: 2015-10-01 02:00:00, dtype: int32

df.loc["2015-10-01 02:00:00",:]
Out[]:

values    2
Name: 2015-10-01 02:00:00, dtype: int32

print(type(df.loc["2015-10-01 02:00:00"]))
print(type(df.loc["2015-10-01 02:00:00",:]))
print(df.loc["2015-10-01 02:00:00"].shape)
print(df.loc["2015-10-01 02:00:00",:].shape)
Out[]:
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
(1,)
(1,)
```

I could wrap any of those in DataFrame like that:

```
slize = pd.DataFrame(df.loc["2015-10-01 02:00:00",:])
Out[]:
        2015-10-01 02:00:00
values                    2
```

Of course I could do this to reach my result:

```
slize.T
Out[]:
                     values
2015-10-01 02:00:00       2
```

But as at this point, I could also expect a column as a series it is kinda hard to test if it is a row or columns series to add the T automatically. 
Did I miss a way of selecting what I want?

Comment: It is a known and wanted behaviour, that loc returns a series at this point.. why would you want to have a dataframe?

Comment: At this point of my code I expect dataframes with datetime index. They should can contain one or many rowes and zero or many columns. And I guess it makes sense in probably most cases that one row is a series, but as a series has no orientation I don't know how to cast this to the right format. But what I found most unexpected, is this resulting in Key error:
    df.loc[["2015-10-01 02:00:00"],:]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend to generate your index using `pd.date_range` for convenience, and then to use `.loc` with a `Timestamp` or `datetime` object.

```
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd

start = datetime(2015, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0)
end = datetime(2015, 10, 1, 4, 0, 0)
dates = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.DatetimeIndex(dates))
df["values"] = range(0,5)
```

Then you can use `.loc` with a `Timestamp` or `datetime` object.

```
In [2]: df.loc[[start]]
Out[2]:
            values
2015-10-01       0
```

### Further details

> Simply using indexing results in a key error:

```
df["2015-10-01 02:00:00"]
Out[]:
KeyError: '2015-10-01 02:00:00'
```

`KeyError` occurs because you try to return a view of the `DataFrame` by looking for a column named `"2015-10-01 02:00:00"`

> Similarly this:

```
df.loc[["2015-10-01 02:00:00"]]
Out[]:
KeyError: "None of [['2015-10-01 02:00:00']] are in the [index]"
```

Your second option cannot work with `str` indexing, you should use [exact indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#exact-indexing) as mentioned instead.

> These surprisingly (?) result in the same series as follows:

```
df.loc["2015-10-01 02:00:00"]
Out[]:
values    2
Name: 2015-10-01 02:00:00, dtype: int32
```

If you use `.loc` on a single row you will have a coercion to `Series` type as you noticed. Hence you shall cast to `DataFrame` and then transpose the result.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I accepted this as it is most detailed and contains the answer of @jezrael + stuff about the other parts. I now continue to work with the "exact indexing". Thanks!

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you! `df.loc["2015-10-01 02:00:00"]` behavior confused me a lot. I was like why you can get a series with a string but you can't get a dataframe with `df.loc[["2015-10-01 02:00:00"]]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df[time_series_row] == “data_to_match”]
```

Sorry for the formatting. On my phone, will update when I’m back at a computer.

Edit:

I would generally write it like this:

```
bitmask = df[time_seried_row] == "data_to_match"
row = df[bitmask]
```

Comment: Ok, I guess I can live with that solution. Well, to be correct for my example it would have to be df[df.index == "2015-10-01 02:00:00"]

Comment: Used that at the beginning, but now changed it to "exact indexing" as noted by @MCMZL and jezrael and hence accepted their questions. Anyhow, thanks for reminding me of this (obvious) way I missed.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert string to datetime - using [exact indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#exact-indexing):

```
print (df.loc[[pd.to_datetime("2015-10-01 02:00:00")]])
                     values
2015-10-01 02:00:00       2
```

Or convert `Series` to `DataFrame` and transpose:

```
print (df.loc["2015-10-01 02:00:00"].to_frame().T)
                     values
2015-10-01 02:00:00       2
```